# Can't add reference to System.ServiceProcess.dll

Tags: asp.net

I am using System.ServiceProcess.dll in my ASP.NET application. I added a reference and intellisense recognizes it. But when I build an application, there is no System.ServiceProcess.dll in bin folder and application says it can't find a namespace. What may be wrong? Can I use this dll in IIS?

This is what I get:

```
 Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ServiceProcess' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Source Error:


Line 5:  using System.Diagnostics;
Line 6:  using System.Linq;
Line 7:  using System.ServiceProcess;
Line 8:  using System.Web;
Line 9:  using System.Web.UI;
```

Comment: set the reference property `Copy Local` to `true`

Comment: System.ServiceProcess.dll is provided as part of the .NET Framework. You should not try to copy it locally, as the version installed in the GAC will always take precedence.

Comment: I don't think you'll see it in the bin folder because its part on the .NET Framework so its in the GAC on your PC or server.

Comment: Can you include the exact error message in the question?

Answer (score 3):

Add a reference in the process to System.ServiceProcess.dll.

To do this, in the solution window, right click on "References" and choose "Add Reference.."  Go to the .NET tab, and double click on System.ServiceProcess.dll.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you added reference to the DLL of wrong .NET version. (so it exists, but when trying to actually compile, it's breaking)

When adding the reference, make sure the version match the version of your project:

[image]